# How to find click event on header in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, grid, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I am using an angular ui grid .
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/102_sorting
I want to show an alert when I click the header icon `V` . Currently it is showing `hello` text when I click the `v` icon. Can I show an alert when I click the icon?

Here is my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UAElQb8dl9qr5Cwmjg6q?p=preview

```
 $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A live demo is <kbd>**[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KCe8jm?p=preview)**</kbd>.

You can access header cell click event by **`headerCellTemplate`** and **`extrenal-scopes`**:

Docs here: [Ui-grid custom templates](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates)

> The custom row template merges all the cells together when the entity.merge value is true.
>
> You can use `grid.appScope` in your row template to access elements in your controller's scope.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name'
    }, {
      field: 'gender'
    }, {
      field: 'company',
      enableSorting: false,
      headerCellTemplate: ''
      +'<div role="columnheader" class="sortable" aria-sort="none">'
        +'<div role="button" class="ui-grid-cell-contents ui-grid-header-cell-primary-focus">'
          +'<span class="ui-grid-header-cell-label ng-binding">Company</span>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<div role="button" class="ui-grid-column-menu-button" aria-label="Column Menu" ng-click="grid.appScope.showAlert();">'
          +'<i class="ui-grid-icon-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>'
        +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
    }],
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
    }
  };

  $scope.showAlert = function() {
    alert('ts');
  }


  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions1" external-scopes="externalScopes" class="grid"></div>

 
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Notice:]**

> I'm not sure is this alert what you want.
> If is or close, this header cell template is a very simple demo, more about default header cell template is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226428/what-is-default-header-cell-template-of-ui-grid)